# How to upgrade the hard drive in a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, migration

I have a MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard that I want to upgrade to a new larger hard drive.  I also have a current Time Machine backup on an external USB drive and an external SATA case I that I can put a 2.5" drive in.

What's the best procedure for transferring the existing installation to the new drive?

Comment: Would help if you specify which MacBook Pro Revision, since the instructions may differ between the Unibody and the earlier models.

Comment: What is the question, exactly? How to physically replace the hard drive or how to transfer the installation? Or both?

Comment: The question is how to transfer the contents of the hard drive, not how to change the physical drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instructions on how to replace the hard drive simply follow the step-by-step instructions in the MacBook Pro Unibody manual available [here](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/MacBook_Pro_13inch_Mid2009.pdf) for the 13" Model for example. You can find your specific manual [here](http://support.apple.com/manuals/)

The process I followed on my MacBook was:

- Put new HDD in external casing
- Use [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) to copy the original drive to the external drive
- Boot off external drive to ensure everything works
- Physically remove the drive and replace using the instructions in the mentioned manual
- Boot MacBook with the new HDD.

Comment: Did you boot off another drive to run SuperDuper, or does it have some way to create a consistent snapshot of the drive you're booted from (i.e. the original drive in the laptop)?

Comment: It runs off the original drive. It will copy the drive while it is in use. It makes an exact copy of the drive.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an alternative to SuperDuper: [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/), which i've used in similar process as Diago explained.